# Rails adds elements to my XML message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently trying to build an integration with our warehouse. They have an API that accepts XML messages. However, when I send them a message (according to the specifications) I keep getting an error that my XML is invalid. I believe Rails is adding elements to my message that I don't want. My code:

```
    x = ::Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent=>2)
    x.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0", :encoding=>"UTF-8"
    x.InventoryXML {
        x.CustomerID("username")
        x.Password("password")
        x.Items {
            x.ItemID(self.name)
        }
    }

    http = Net::HTTP.new("www.webgistix.com")
    response = http.post("/XML/GetInventoryForSelectedItems.asp", x.to_xml)
    answer = self.evaluate_smartfill_response(response)
    return x.to_s + "\n Response: " + answer.to_s
```

When I print the return, this is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<InventoryXML> 
  <CustomerID>username</CustomerID> 
  <Password>password</Password> 
  <Items> 
    <ItemID>item</ItemID> 
  </Items>         
</InventoryXML> 
<inspect/> <to_xml/> <to_s/>
```

Error:

> Error: There was an error processing your request. Please check your request and try again.

I think the added tags at the end of my message might be the problem. Where are these tags coming from and how do I prevent them from being added to my message?

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code and this seemed to fix it:

```
    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
        xml.InventoryXML {
            xml.CustomerID("customer")
            xml.Password("password")
            xml.Items {
                xml.ItemID(self.name)
            }
        }
    end
    http = Net::HTTP.new("www.webgistix.com")
    response = http.post("/XML/GetInventoryForSelectedItems.asp", builder.to_xml)
    answer = self.evaluate_smartfill_response(response)
    return builder.to_xml + "\n\n Response: " + answer.to_s
```